# DEPRECATION WARNING: Method length is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Faced with such a "warning" in line of code.
DEPRECATION WARNING: Method length is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash. Using this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you continue to use this method you may be creating a security vulnerability in your app that can be exploited. Instead, consider using one of these documented methods which are not deprecated: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.2/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

```
if params[:q].blank? && params[:advanced_search].blank? || params[:q]&.length == 1 && params[:q][:s].present?
  @q.add_default_condition('status', 'in', 'open')
  session[:last_ticket_search] = nil
end
```

`params[:q]&.length == 1`  What alternatives can be used?

`params[:q].to_unsafe_h&.length == 1` Can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the second part of the check in Rails 5.1 like this using the `dig` method.

```
params.to_unsafe_h.dig(:q, :s).present?
```

Using `length` in Rails 5.1 is a bit tricky, since the `params` now includes both `controller` and `action` keys, so be aware of that.

Comment: What is this method?